# How the function call will work in a stateful widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have made a function in one of my stateful widgets and I am calling it periodically so once I exit the screen will the function still be called.
I am making a api call periodically and on error of that call I show a snackbar so some times when I exit the application the snakbar keeps on appearing.

```
     @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadMessages();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> loadMessages() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = await chatVM.fetchConvoApi();

    List<dynamic> messagesJson = data['messages'];

    setState(() {
      if (messagesJson.isEmpty == false) {
        _messages = messagesJson.map((e) => Message.fromJson(e)).toList();
      }
      startLoadingNewMessagesPeriodically();
    });
  }

  Future<void> loadNewMessages() async {
    String? time;
    if (_messages.isNotEmpty) {
      time = _messages[_messages.length - 1].sentTime;
    }
    Map<String, dynamic> data =
        await chatVM.fetchLatestApi(time ?? DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
    List<dynamic> messagesJson = data['messages'];
    if (messagesJson.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        _messages.addAll(messagesJson.map((e) => Message.fromJson(e)).toList());
      });
    }
  }

  void startLoadingNewMessagesPeriodically() {
    Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
      // Your code to load new messages here
      loadNewMessages();
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you provide some code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

With your explanation, it's a bit difficult to understand what's happening. Can you give me more information about it?

There are two possible scenarios that I am thinking

1. Your Stateful widget is still in your widget tree.

Technically, if you don't have Stateful Wiget in your widget tree, it won't call any function. So I recommend you check your Widget tree in your Devtools. If it's still in your widget tree, make sure it's unmounted from your widget tree.

2. Check the `dispose()` method of your state Widget.

Did you add any new methods on your `dispose()` method of `State` Widget? In that case, it may have some sort of side effect when `dispose()` is called.

Comment: i have added the code it is happening because i am using set state in a timer how can i solve this issue